# v-for list re-renders all styles when manipulating array

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a `v-for` list that renders items from an array. The problem is that when I manipulate the array, all the components are re-rendered entirely from the ground up. This is especially visible in the CSS styles that have changed depending on their position in the array.

When I alter the array, why are all the previous components (DOM elements) also completely re-rendered? This seems super-inefficient!

If you did this with pure javascript you would just append/prepend a DOM element to the existing DOM and keep your hands off the items that were already there.

Components

```
<card v-for="q in questions">{{q}}</card>
```

Array manipulation

```
if(this.questions.length > 4) this.questions.pop()
this.questions.unshift(this.question)
```

Ehm, so I guess my question is, does `v-for` always need to do this, or can you disable it?

Answer (score 1):

[From the Documentation:](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#key)

> When Vue is updating a list of elements rendered with `v-for`, by default it uses an “in-place patch” strategy. If the order of the data items has changed, instead of moving the DOM elements to match the order of the items, Vue will patch each element in-place and make sure it reflects what should be rendered at that particular index.

<!>

> To give Vue a hint so that it can track each node’s identity, and thus reuse and reorder existing elements, you need to provide a unique key attribute for each item. An ideal value for key would be the unique id of each item.

---

In your case (assuming each question object has a unique `id` property):

```
<card v-for="q in questions" :key="q.id">{{ q }}</card>
```

---

While using the `key` attribute is not explicitly required, [it is an essential rule](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/style-guide/#Keyed-v-for-essential) ([Priority A](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/style-guide/#Priority-A-Essential)) in the official Vue style guide. Effectively, you should always use a `key` with `v-for`.